# What is the outward normal vector at the end points of the one-dimensional line?

Tags: integration, geometry, orthonormal

In the one-dimensional space, suppose the interval $[a, b]$ exists on the real line with boundary points $a$ and $b$.

What is the outward normal vector at the point $a$ and at the point $b$?

The answer is $-1$ for $a$ and $1$ for $b$. But I cannot understand why so.

Usually, the outward normal vector is perpendicular to the line.
But in this case, aren't they tangent to the line itself?

I can't digest what's "normal" in the $1$-D case.

I can kind of get that the interval ends at $a$ and at $b$ and so the outward direction is to $-1$ and to $1$, respectively...but is there a mathematical way to express this in the $1$-D case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A "tangent vector" to the number line is a real number. But the only tangent vector to a point on the number line, viewed as a $0$-dimensional submanifold of a $1$-dimensional ambient space, is the velocity of a constant path, i.e., $0$. *Every* non-zero real number is therefore a normal vector to any particular point. The numbers $1$ at $b$ and $-1$ at $a$ are tangent vectors to the real line, but are normal vectors to the endpoints viewed as a $0$-manifold, and are the unique choices that are outward pointing from $[a, b]$.

This phenomenon looks weird at first glance, but is correct on closer inspection. Think of a curve in the plane. A normal vector to the curve is still *tangent* to the plane.

Comment: ...are the unique **unit** choices that are outward-pointing.

Comment: thanks! so is it correct to think that in n-dimensional space, if your normal vector is to the n-1 dimensional object, then it can only be tangent to the n dimensional space? the curve in the plane makes sense to me visually but if I think of a plane in the 3D world then again, i don’t see what’s normal to the 3D object either. let’s say we define what’s normal, would it be then again tangent to the 3D object again...?

Comment: i meant, “if I think of a plane in the 3D world, then again, i don’t see what’s tangent to the 3D object either, let’s say we found the vector which is outward normal to the plane living on the 3D object, is this vector tangent to the 3D object?” i am imagining a ball, a surface of a ball, and a line coming out normal to this surface, and thinking, how is this line tangent to the “ball”? also, where in math area can I read more fundamental concepts in this area?

Comment: "Tangents" are intrinsic to an object, but "normal" is defined only with respect to an "ambient space"; pretty much by definition _all_ vectors are tangent to the ambient space. <> For a circle in a plane, there is a unique normal direction or normal line at each point. If we put a circle in three-space, there is a normal _plane_ at each point. For a ball in three-space, there is a tangent plane and a normal line at each point. <> Linear algebra covers the pointwise concepts, but you're really asking about "manifolds". _Differential Topology_ by Guillemin and Pollack is a nice reference.